# Java/Groovy String.Format How to handle runtime % in the string to be formatted

Tags: java, string, groovy, format, string.format

Problem that I am facing is that with String.format is a runtime message is having a percent character then it errors out.

For eg. in groovy:

```
def q = "What are your %age?" 
def percent = 91
println formatMessage("Question: ${q} \n Answer: %d", percent)


String formatMessage(String message, Object... messageParams) {
return String.format(message, messageParams)
}
```

Now when calling formatMessage if message argument is prepared at runtime from interpolating the string from a variable which is having a valid % character, this results in UnknownFormatConversionException

Now as formatMessage method is getting called at multiple places, we do not want caller to sanitize the message before calling it.

Is there a way to identify and escape % within formatMessage method before calling String.format?

Comment: Use `%s` instead of `${q}` and pass it too?

Comment: Use %%age instead of %age

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def q = "What are your %age?" 
def percent = 91
println formatMessage("Question: ${q} \n Answer: %d", percent)

@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
String formatMessage(CharSequence message, Object... messageParams) {
    if(message instanceof GString){
        //if message is a GString then build a new one with replaced values
        message=new org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl(
                message.getValues().collect{ it instanceof CharSequence ? it.replaceAll('%','%%') : it } as Object[], 
                message.getStrings()
            )

    }
    return String.format(message as String, messageParams)
}
```

Comment: That's really great. Didn't knew that we can iterate the values in an interpolated string. This definitely solves the problem where groovy string interpolation is being used, but when normal string concatenation is used (see eg below) , problem is still there. Any thoughts on how that can be solved. 

println formatMessage("Question: " + q + "\n Answer: %d", percent)

Comment: so, put `q` into parameters as you did for `percent`: `formatMessage("Question: %s \n Answer: %d", q, percent)`

Comment: Problem is we cannot control what people will put. Hence the issue.

Comment: Formatting is a metaprogramming. If you give users ability to use placeholder `%d` then teach them to escape each `%` with `%%`

Comment: Exactly that is what my opinion is, however we wanted to avoid as many edge case scenarios as possible. GString solution helps alot in this case. Thanks @daggett.